# Question about product topology in the reverse direction

Tags: general-topology

If I have shown that a set $U\times V$ is open in $X\times Y$, does it mean that $U$ is open in X and $V$ open in Y?

Is there way to prove it? If not, is there a counter example?

Comment: The two projections onto the coordinates are open maps.

Answer (score 3):

No: If $U$ is *any* subset of $X$ then $U\times \emptyset$ is open in $X\times Y$.

Yes if both $U$ and $V$ are non-empty. Suppose $x\in U$. Choose any $y\in V$ you like. Now since $(x,y)\in U\times V$ the definition of the product topology shows that...

Comment: I am confused about the first part "No" - how is $U \times \emptyset$ open in $X\times Y$ where $U$ is any subset of $X$? The condition must be $U$ is an "open subset" of $X$.

Comment: @DonaldObama $U \times \emptyset = \emptyset$, which is open in any space.